# How to delete a file from folder by using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

While uploading csv file iam saving that file in uploads folder if the file uplaoded successfully into database or  not uploaded then also it should be deleted automatically from that folder.Can any one help me regarding this.

```
$data['error'] = '';      
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
$config['max_size'] = '10000';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
  $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
} 
else {
  $file_data = $this->upload->data();
  $file_path =  './uploads/'.$file_data['file_name'];
  $csv_array = $this->csvimport->get_array($file_path,'',FALSE,0,3,0,$cformat);   

  if ($csv_array) {
    $successflag=true;

    foreach ($csv_array as $row) {
      $order = array(                  
        'department'=>$row['Department'],
        'gender'=>$row['Gender'],             
      );    
      $query = $this->db->query("select count(*) cnt from order_master where order_id='{$order['order_id']}' ");
      $row = $query->first_row();

      if(trim($order['order_id'] )!="" && $row->cnt==0 ) {
        $this->masterorder_model->order($order);             
      }
      else if (  $row->cnt>0) {
        $successflag=false;
        $this->flash->success("<h5><font color='red'>Found Duplicate Order Id'{$order['order_id']}' for order name '$oname'</font></h5>");
        break;
      }    
    }

    if(!$successflag) {
      $this->db->trans_rollback();     
    }
    else {
      $this->db->trans_commit();
      $this->flash->success('<h5>Csv Data Imported Successfully.</h5>');
    }
    redirect(base_url().'masterorder/index');
  }
  else {
    $this->flash->success('<h5><font color="red">Invalid file format.</font></h5>');
    redirect(base_url().'masterorder/index');
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**unlink()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) to delete file after processing.

> Deletes filename. Similar to the Unix C unlink() function. A E_WARNING
>   level error will be generated on failure.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the **file helper** for the codeigniter.

So it would be like as below :

```
$this->load->helper("file");
delete_files($path);
```

Please visit [this](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/file_helper.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unlink('path/filename' )`

Comment: i cant get u were to use this

Comment: @user2630366 give the path/filename unlink('path/filename' ); in your condition

Comment: @user2630366 chmod("/path/filename", 777); before that

Comment: @user2630366 it is for changing file permissions